# Auto-suggestions with HTML on stack overflow causes rendering issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, xss, duplicate-suggestions

I was entering an issue on Stack Overflow and one of the auto-suggestions had HTML in the title, and it seemed to break the rendering in my browser.  I'm using the latest stable FireFox for Windows 8.1.

Title of question to reproduce the issue:

```
Showing m.bing.com in the WebBrowser control
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: +1 reproduced with latest Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Win7 x64

Comment: reproduced with FireFox 26.0 on Win7 x64 as well.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 31.0.1650.63 on Ubuntu 13.04 as well.

Comment: reproduced in IE11 on win7 x64 as well.

Comment: Actually the HTML is not in the title, it's in the body of the question which is loaded as the tooltip of the suggestion. Still a severe bug though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.1.8.1834` in meta and `2014.8.1285` on sites.